# Casperjs equivalent of var dump

Tags: casperjs

I would like to know whats equivalent of `var_dump` in casper js ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To [serialize](http://casperjs.org/api.html#utils.serialize) any var contents as JSON:

```
var serialized = require('utils').serialize(yourVar);
```

To directly [dump](http://casperjs.org/api.html#utils.dump) the JSON serialization to the console:

```
require('utils').dump(yourVar);
```